# Rancher is having permission issues

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, rancher, rancher-desktop

I'm trying to run some containers.

one of them is a mongodb, but always when running `docker-compose up -d` it gives this permission error.

```
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/data/mongodb': chown /data/mongodb: permission denied
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.